# Get device resolution Xamarin.iOS 8

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

How can I get the resolution of the screen in Xamarin.iOS 8?

I tried UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale and UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height but I get 0.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those are the properties you want to use to obtain this information.

This is very odd, because this works even from the "Main" method, even before FinishedLaunching is invoked.

Comment: I tired inspecting the objects at runtime. But unlike other C# projects, it's not proper and cannot see the properties and values in xamarin.ios c# projects. Do you have any idea?